# Non-contiguous array pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am writing wrapper code for several linear algebra libraries in C++ which may store their arrays in one of several formats, the most common being dense column-major, dense row-major, compressed sparse column, and compressed sparse row. I would like to create either an array wrapper class that will access the elements of these arrays in a universal order, while maintaining the underlying memory order required by the base library; that is, I want to be able to access, say, the elements of both a wrapped column-major dense array and a wrapped row-major dense array the same way, using row-based indexing. I cannot reorder the underlying arrays without interfering with the function of the external libraries, and reordering would involve substantial computational cost anyway given the huge size of my arrays. Here's what I mean, supposing both 'rowMajorArray' and 'columnMajorArray' store values of type 'T' in the appropriate orders for their external library:

```
T * data;
// Initialize values of data

rowMajorArray R(data); // Stored row-major, with reordering of data if necessary
columnMajorArray C(data); // Stored column-major, with reordering of data if necessary

wrapperArray wrapperR(R); // DOES NOT reorder data
wrapperArray wrapperC(C); // DOES NOT reorder data

assert(wrapperR[3] == wrapperC[3]); // I want this to be true, i.e. transparent row indexing
assert(wrapperR[3][4] == wrapperC[3][4]); // I want this to be true, i.e. transparent element indexing


T * rowPointerR = wrapperR[0]; // Points to first row; should this be a reference: &(wrapperR[0]) ?
T * rowPointerC = wrapperC[0]; // Points to first row, even though stored column-major

assert( *(rowPointerR + 2) == *(rowPointerC + 2) ) // I want this to be true, i.e. transparent row pointers

T * elementPointerR = &(wrapperR[0][0]); // Points to individual element
T * elementPointerC = &(wrapperC[0][0]); // Points to individual element

assert( *(elementPointerR + 2) == *(elementPointerC + 2) ) // I want this to be true, i.e. transparent pointer arithmetic
```

Essentially my goal is for the underlying libraries to be able to access the wrapped arrays using the same memory ordering as they natively use, while enabling my wrapper code to transparently access the data without worrying about the underlying memory order. I don't care whether I use pointer or indexing syntax, as I can do everything I need with either, as long as I can get correct access to both rows and elements; if I can only directly implement pointers, I will then overload indexing operators anyway, to allow easy integration with other external operator-overloaded libraries.

Thanks in advance for your help everybody.

Comment: Usually it helps if questions include--you know--a question.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to overload the indexing operator and, inside of said operator, calculate the correct offset. Your wrapper will need to know what kind of data structure it is wrapping.  It may be as simple as setting a few member variables when you create an instance of one of these types, i.e., `m_rowOffset`, `m_columnOffset`, etc.

However, you can't do anything about how pointers work.  Pointers are simple, dumb creatures and you can't make them work differently to suit your purpose.  If you add `1` to a pointer it is simply going to advance to the next object (i.e., advance `n * sizeof(T)` bytes)  Stick with the indexing approach.  It's more natural anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly would discourage you from using multi-dimensional arrays and infix operators.

A naive starting point would be a simple interface like this.

```
class Table {
public:
  virtual ~Table() {}

  virtual double get(size_t row, size_t col) const = 0;
  virtual void getRow(size_t row, std::vector<double> &row_vals) const = 0;
  virtual void getCol(size_t col, std::vector<double> &col_vals) const = 0;

  virtual void set(size_t row, size_t col, double val) = 0;
  virtual void setRow(size_t row, const std::vector<double> &row_vals) = 0;
  virtual void setCol(size_t col, const std::vector<double> &col_vals) = 0;
};
```

You'd implement the interface for each storage strategy.  This would allow the row/col major to optimize where they excel.